# PDF::Table Perl module not working on Debian Jessie

Tags: perl, perl-module, debian-jessie

When I try to use [PDF::Table](http://search.cpan.org/~omega/PDF-Table-0.9.14/lib/PDF/Table.pm) module on Debian Jessie (Perl 5.20), I get this message:

```
Useless use of greediness modifier '?' in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(\S{20}? <-- HERE )(?=\S)/ at /usr/share/perl5/PDF/Table.pm line 370.
```

This module works great on Debian Wheezy (with Perl 5.014002) but an upgrade in Perl 5.20 seems to make it unusable on Debian Jessie. The only [documentation](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=762533) I found on this bug talks about the Perl upgrade, but doesn't give any solution to fix that. The script I use is the PDF::Table main example on CPAN:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use PDF::API2;
 use PDF::Table;

 my $pdftable = new PDF::Table;
 my $pdf = new PDF::API2(-file => "table_of_lorem.pdf");
 my $page = $pdf->page;

 # some data to layout
 my $some_data =[
    ["1 Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "Donec odio neque, faucibus vel",
    "consequat quis, tincidunt vel, felis."],
    ["Nulla euismod sem eget neque.",
    "Donec odio neque",
    "Sed eu velit."],
    #... and so on
 ];

my $left_edge_of_table = 50;
 # build the table layout
 $pdftable->table(
     # required params
     $pdf,
     $page,
     $some_data,
     x => $left_edge_of_table,
     w => 495,
     start_y => 500,
     start_h => 300,
     # some optional params
     next_y  => 750,
     next_h  => 500,
     padding => 5,
     padding_right => 10,
     background_color_odd  => "gray",
     background_color_even => "lightblue", #cell background color for even rows
  );

$pdf->saveas("table_of_lorem.pdf");

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Ok";
```

My hoster only says that I have to "adapt my code"... Can you please help me to find the right way to do that? I only noticed this bug when using PDF::Table, but is there a possibilty to have the same problem with another Perl module on Perl 5.20? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you please check what version of PDF::Table is installed? That specific release might be broken. Run `perl -MPDF::Table\ 99` (including the space). it will complain that it only has a lower version.

Comment: The issue you are seeing [was fixed in version 0.9.10](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/PDF-Table#L23). You could just install the latest version manually from CPAN, or use a local::lib for your project so it doesn't interfere with the system Perl (though for that module I think that's not an issue because it doesn't have any dependencies that might be updated besides Carp).

Comment: Hi. I tried on perl 5.22 with PDF::API2 version 2.025 and PDF::Table version 0.9.6 and the code seems to work (write Ok and generate a pdf file) in spite of the message (which is just a warning in my view).

Comment: Yes, [it's a warning](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Useless-use-of-greediness-modifier-'%25c'-in-regex%3b-marked-by-%3c---HERE-in-m%2f%25s%2f). But you can still update. You don't _have to_ use the system packages for your Perl modules. You can install newer versions if you want.

Comment: The version of PDF::Table installed on the server is 0.9.6. Installing the latest version (0.9.14) as a lib solves the problem on Perl 5.20. Thank you so much to both of you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is a warning. It's annoying, but it can be ignored. The module was fixed [in version 0.9.10](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/PDF-Table#L23). You can install that from CPAN directly instead of using the system package and then the warning will go away.